# Change hyper parameter model of Keras regularizer during training time

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have two questions about trainable parameters in Keras:

1. I'm designing my own regularizer `myReg` for a Keras model `Model_1`, where the regularizer `R` has a hyper parameter which is another Keras model `Model_2`.

```py
class myReg(Regularizer):
    def __init__(self, Model_2):
        self.model = Model_2
```

But since `Model_1` and `Model_2` are trained alternatively, `Model_2` will get updated. Will `myReg` also get updated during the training time of `Model_1`? I did some experiments but I'm still not sure if it will work. I read a lot of questions about change hyper parameters of regularizer during training time, and people in this question https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/4813 uses `K.set_value`.

Does anyone know whether or not `Model_2` will actually get updated? If not, is there way to make it updated?

2. When I have some trainable parameters, say `layer.trainable_weights`, but I want to sort the weights before feed into some other operations, how can I do that? Can I use something like

```py
import tensorflow as tf
p = layer.trainable_weights
p = tf.sort(p)
```

or are there any particular ways in Keras?

Really appreciate if someone can answer my questions, thanks in advance!

Comment: Q1 is very unclear. Q2 in general the answer is NO if you want to compute gradients on the input trainable weights. Because operations like `sort` are not directly compatible with gradient computation. Of course, you may manually guide how to compute gradients.

Comment: @pitfall Thanks for your answer for Q2! For Q1, I admit I'm doing something unusual. I want to train `Model_1` and `Model_2` alternatively like a GAN, while `Model_2` is also a hyper parameter for `Model_1`'s regularizer `myReg` (`myReg.Model_2`). My question is, when `Model_1` and `Model_2` training alternatively, will `myReg.Model_2` also get updated as `Model_2` training and update its parameters? Hope this is clear enough, and really appreciate if you can also help me with this question!

Comment: Not sure the exact way you described here will lead to the behavior you expect. But I am sure it is possible. As a quick check, I think all you need to do is to print `myReg.Model_2` and see whether its parameters change as`model_2` converges.